# Making Credit Card Payment from Android / Blackberry

Tags: android, drupal, blackberry, payment

I have an mobile application (on Android & BB) which interacts with the Drupal site via web services. Users are required to pay a amount for registering on the site which is achieved by UberCart module of Drupal.

Now, I want to have a registration process from my mobile apps too which requires the payment from the app.

@Drupal Guys - Can drupal web services can be used for the payment also? Any security risks or loopholes?
@Android/BB Guys - What are the possible ways of having a payment solution from the app.

Thanks in Advance

Cheers,
Prateek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out PayPal Mobile

```
https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile
```

It has API and library to use in Android.
From right side of the page, you can download the Android required library and also development guide.

Comment: Thanks Sarwar !! But, this is just for the Paypal right? What if I want to make a payment using Credit Cards etc?

Comment: Paypal can process credit cards also... But, check the commission rate whether that are good for you or not. It is good to stick to verified providers because, people will rather feel safe to enter credit card details if you take card info via PayPal (or similar renowned service). Some people might not want to enter card details in text boxes in your application. Because, unlike apple appstore, Android app or publishers are not verified.

Comment: Yes, thats what my concern is. People won't enter there credit card information unless it is from the verified providers.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar task, though I am still far from the finish line.
As I see it, the payment should be via Ubercart and not directly via the "payment gateway".
To do so, you should get the Ubercart "processing" via the Services module. I can't tell whether it is available already or needed to be developed.
Regarding to security - use SSL for the entire connection between the application and the Drupal Services.

Hope it helps somehow, and I would appreciate to hear even more about your experience. Maybe we can share forces to make it happen faster...

Regards,
Shushu

Comment: Even I am not sure if "Ubercart" processing is available via web services if not the whole process will be similar to what "Andoid Checkout" does, which requires lot of effort. Will keep you posted if I get some leads on this.

Comment: Thanks. My plan is to "make it happen" - Ubercart processing via Services module. But any shortcut using existing modules will be a great help...

Comment: Shushu - Can we use google checkout for the in-app payment? I am not able to find any API's for that

Comment: Can't find anything easily as well. Except from few places where it is written it is possible, I don't see any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my service at http://OpenPayments.Mobii. We offer a set of very advanced FREE services to incorporate In-App Purchases from any platform including Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone, etc. We currently offer PayPal and Google checkout payments, we have support for time-limited licenses, automatic license recovery, app refund policies, and much more.